# How could I make a thread loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

Every 3 seconds, I want the server to send a message.
To do this, I have this code.

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        getPackets().sendGameMessage("[Server Message]: Remember to vote!");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code works of course, waits 3 and a half seconds, sends the message.
But how can I make it loop, so every 3 and a half seconds, it will send it without stopping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a Timer. See [Java how to write a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100353/java-how-to-write-a-timer)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit surprised that someone tackling networking in Java doesn't know how to put code in an infinite loop.  Thus, I wonder if your real question is "is there a better way?"

To that question, I would say that you should consider using either `java.util.Timer` to send the message, or using `scheduleAtFixedRate()` from a `ScheduledExecutorService` obtained from `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()`.

Comment: My guess is self taught.  Probably picked up a video game book and went straight to the chapter about making a multi-player game.

Answer (score 0):

spawn the above code in a separate thread and enclose it within a while(true) loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, mind giving an example of that, for reference and future reference?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code is not very useful because it blocks the current thread and also seems to unnecessarily clutter the program logic. It's better to delegate it to a worker thread that executes the send in the background. Also `Thread.sleep` is known to be inaccurate.

As of the latest Java versions, I think the most elegant way to do it is using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThraedPoolExecutor(1);
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
               getPackets().sendGameMessage("[Server Message]: Remember to vote!");
          }
    }, 0, 3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Also you don't have to worry about that annoying `InterruptedException`.